# How change button's position in pop-up ionic 1

Tags: css, angularjs, button, ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deVmh.png)

I need put the button green **under of the Three buttons**! someone help me please!

My **code Here**:

```
 $scope.showIntroductionPage = function(childs){
  if(childs == 0){

    var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({

    title: 'Welcome to Lens Changer',
    subTitle: 'You can choose a option!',
    cssClass: 'popup-intro',

    buttons: [
      { type: 'button-assertive',
        text: '<b><font size="2">Parent</font></b>',
        cssClass: 'button-popup_red',
        onTap: function(e) {

        }
      },
      { type: 'button-energized' ,
        text: '<b><font size="2">Educator</font></b>',
        onTap: function(e) {

        }
      },
      { type: 'button-calm' ,
        text: '<b><font size="2">Sign in</font></b>',
        onTap: function(e) {

        }
      },
      { type: 'button-balanced',
        text: '<div><b><font size="2">Ready</font></b></div>',
        onTap: function(e) {
          myPopup.close();
        }
      }
      ]
    }

  );
};
```

- I don't know change this green button.

Note: that since we allow the above HTML tags, to have tags show up as text you need to escape the < character. You can escape '<' by marking it as code (with indentation or backticks as is done below) or by using the HTML entity <

Allowed Attributes

img Attributes

Comment: Can you put your code here?

Comment: or create a jsfiddle

Comment: ok! I had update my aks, the code is up

Answer (score 0):

i have never used this but this might help.

```
buttons: [
  {
    text: '<div>'
  },
  { type: 'button-assertive',
    text: '<b><font size="2">Parent</font></b>',
    cssClass: 'button-popup_red',
    onTap: function(e) {

    }
  },
  { type: 'button-energized' ,
    text: '<b><font size="2">Educator</font></b>',
    onTap: function(e) {

    }
  },
  { type: 'button-calm' ,
    text: '<b><font size="2">Sign in</font></b>',
    onTap: function(e) {

    }
  },
  {
    text: '</div>'
  },
  { type: 'button-balanced',
    text: '<div><b><font size="2">Ready</font></b></div>',
    onTap: function(e) {
      myPopup.close();
    }
  }
  ]
```

my result here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fQEN.png)

Comment: I try but the green button just move to right, the two <div> are like a button more in the array of buttons. T.T

Comment: You can see the image more up in your code. thanks bro